# When should I call a close method of a SQLite database in Android

Tags: android

I want to know when a close method of a sqlite database should be called in a life cycle, since the NotePad sample in the sdk (http://developer.android.com/resources/tutorials/notepad/index.html) doesn't call NotesDbAdapter.close(), it implements that method though.

My application accesses the db not so frequently, but some, it depends on user requests. I think I should open the db at the onCreate, and close it at the onDestroy. Is that a good practice?

Thanks in advance,
yokyo

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> I think I should open the db at the
>   onCreate, and close it at the
>   onDestroy. Is that a good practice?

Yes, that is a fine pattern to use.

Comment: Thanks CommonsWare. You assured me ;)

Comment: No, it is not. As stated in the developer pages the onDestroy method will not be called if the system kills the process due to low memory. You should use the onPause method for this. http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html#onDestroy%28%29

Comment: @Will Kru: No, `onDestroy()` is OK. If the process is terminated, apparently there is no harm -- everything is persisted as a part of the database transactions.

Comment: Could you elaborate on that? Obviously when an application is closed by the system while in onPause, onDestroy is not being called, the database isn't closed and a memory leak will occur? EDIT: @kirk woll: thanks for pointing that out, didn't know I could do that, still learning about this site!

Comment: @Will Kru: No, a memory leak will not occur, because the process is being terminated, and so all memory is freed by definition. If you have further questions on this topic, please open your own StackOverflow question.